# Installing Kompozer

Tags: html, editor

I just read about Kompozer and wanted to install the software. Have downloaded the kompozer zip file into my downloads and found installation 'instructions' here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallKompozer

This, however, does not tell me anything. What do these code snippets mean? How do I install the software? Where does one begin?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: I'd recommend against using that because it's quite old. NVU and Kompozer were of the same code base. Kompozer has been stalled and NVU is discontinued in favor of BlueGriffon http://bluegriffon.org/ I'd recommend using that instead.

Answer (score 1):

From the link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallKompozer

Use packages from 12.04 Precise
These packages are installable on at least the 12.10, 13.04 and 14.04 releases.

First, install dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libfontconfig1 libfreetype6 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk2.0-0  libidl0 libnspr4 libnss3 libpango1.0-0 libpng12-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libxft2 libxinerama1 libxrender1 libxt6 zlib1g
```

Then, get the two packages, and install them in the correct order.

For 32bit systems:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer-data_0.8%7Eb3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer_0.8%7Eb3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i kompozer-data_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i kompozer_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_i386.deb
```

for 64bit systems:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer-data_0.8%7Eb3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer_0.8%7Eb3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i kompozer-data_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i kompozer_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

You can now find kompozer in the menu.

### -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Now what does  of this mean. Open your terminal (ctrl+t or from searching for key terminal in Dash)

```
sudo apt-get install libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libfontconfig1 libfreetype6 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk2.0-0  libidl0 libnspr4 libnss3 libpango1.0-0 libpng12-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libxft2 libxinerama1 libxrender1 libxt6 zlib1g
```

This is a command that installs the listed libraries. Those libraries are needed to make Kompozer installable.

Next you have to choose whether your system is 32 or 64 bit.Run the command

```
uname -m
```

if the output is x86_64 then you are 64 bit so you have to work on commands for 64 else use those for 32.

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer-data_0.8%7Eb3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
```

wget is a command that get some download from a given URL and here the command is downloading the .deb package of kompozer-data

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer_0.8%7Eb3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

wget is a command that get some download from a given URL and here the command is downloading the .deb package of kompozer

dpkg is  a command for low level package management. `dpkg -i` means install the package and sure you have to use `sudo` since dealing with package management needs some previliges.

```
sudo dpkg -i kompozer-data_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
```

Here you are going to install the kompozer-data

```
sudo dpkg -i kompozer_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Here you are going to install kompozer

---

**Ps:** It's not maintained anymore, so it's better to use some other alteratives such as Aptana, Blue Fish, etc...

[check this for some choices](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2013/06/18/10-best-alternatives-to-adobe-dreamweaver/)